# Не получаю callback при нажатии на кнопку в telegram

Tags: php, api, telegram

При реализации inline кнопки не работает обратный ответ от telegram,то есть не приходит даже запрос CallbackQuery.

```
function sendTelegram($method, $response)
    {
        $ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot' . TOKEN . '/' . $method."?".http_build_query($response));  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $res = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        return $res;
    }


    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $data = json_decode($data, TRUE);

    $callback_query = $data['callback_query'];
    $callback_data = $callback_query['data'];

    $callback_mess=$callback_query['message']['text'];

if(isset($data['callback_query'])){
    sendTelegram(
                    'sendMessage', 
                    array(
                        'chat_id' => $data['message']['chat']['id'],
                        'text' => $callback_data,


                    )
                );
}
```

Сама клавиша

```
 $inline_keyboard=array(
    "inline_keyboard" => array(array(array("text" => "Обменять!", "callback_data" => "".$elem['id'])))
);
```

В ней самой ошибки(проверял через гет запрос в браузере, вернуло все ОК)

В чем возможна проблема?